# Spark streaming jobs duration in program

Tags: spark-streaming, rdd

How do I get in my program (which is running the spark streaming job) the time taken for each rdd job.
for example

```
val streamrdd = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder,StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet) 

val processrdd = streamrdd.map(some operations...).savetoxyz
```

In the above code for each microbatch rdd the job is run for map and saveto operation.

I want to get the timetake for each streaming job. I can see the job in port 4040 UI, but want to get in the spark code itself.

Pardon if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the StreamingListener in you spark app. This interface provides a method onBatchComplete that can give you total time taken by the batch jobs.

`context.addStreamingListener(new StatusListenerImpl());`

StatusListenerImpl is the implementation class that you have to implement using StreamingListener.
There are more other methods also available in listener you should explore them as well.

Comment: Thank you  implemeting StreamingListener got what I wanted.